# How can I obtain the url of a URL using a Azure CLI command?

Tags: backup, azure

I have created an Azure storage account called 'mystore' and container called 'backups'. I want to create a backup service for my WebApp 'ABCWebApp' which will use this container using the following Azure CLI command:

```
az webapp config backup create --resource-group resXXX --webapp-name ABCWebApp --container-url JJJJ
```

Question: How can I obtain the --container-url - i.e. JJJJ using an Azure CLI command?

I used the Portal UI to create the backup service and then used the following CLI command to get its storage account url which I presume is the same as the value I need for --container-url.

```
az webapp config backup list --resource-group resXXX --webapp-name ABCWebApp
```

The format of the returned url is:

```
"storageAccountUrl": "https://mystore.blob.core.windows.net/backups?sp=rwdl&st=2020-09-10T13:44:36Z&se=2294-06-25T13:44:36Z&sv=2019-12-12&sr=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

How do I get the same using a CLI command without first using the Portal to create the Backup service?

Answer (score 0):

The container-url (JJJJ) is formed from the account name and container name with an appended shared access signature (SAS) - i.e.

```
 https://[account name].blob.core.windows.net/[container name]?SAS.
```

Therefore what I really needed to know is how to get a SAS for my container. For that I first need to get the account-key which is returned in the connection string returned by

```
az storage account show-connection-string --name mystore --resource-group resXXX
```

I can then create a SAS using the following command where KKKK is the account-key return by the above command

```
az storage container generate-sas --account-key KKKK --account-name mystore --name backups --start '2020-09-18' --expiry '2120-01-01' --permissions rwdl
```

The SAS returned by this command is then appended to the url:

```
 https://mystore.blob.core.windows.net/backups?st=2020-09-18&se=2120-01-01&sp=rwdl&sv=2018-11-09&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

This is JJJJ i.e. the --acount-url I need for creating a backup for my webapp

```
az webapp config backup create --resource-group resXXX --webapp-name ABCWebApp --container-url JJJJ
```